# JQuery Not Being Parsed For Only Certain Users Even Though JavaScript Enabled in Browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome, firefox

I have a test system with a dozen test users.  The system is built on the Zend Framework using PHP5 and JQuery.  About 3 of the dozen users are having a problem with the login page; when they click the button nothing happens. This problem occurs in Firefox and Chrome.

The normal process flow is that when the login submit button is clicked, a light validation happens for username and password and then the login form is submitted:

```
//Submits form
$('#login_btn').live('click', function() {

    var uname = $('#form_30296_userid').val();
    var pw = $('#form_30296_userpwd').val();

    if(uname == '' || pw == '')
        alert('You must enter a valid username and password.');
    else
        $("form").submit(); 
});
```

I've confirmed it's not an obvious code issue, as this works just fine for all other users.

Here are the steps I have taken so far:

1. Added a test alert [alert('!')] before any other events happen for
   onclick event.
2. Created a notice that will appear if a user does not have JavaScript enabled in their browsers
3. Personally verified that JavaScript was enabled in Firefox and
   Chrome for users with issues.

I personally logged into the users' system and did not see the JS notice and made sure JS was enabled,  but when I tried clicking the button I did not seven see the test "!" pop up.

Any idea what's going on here?  JavaScript is enabled, so is it a matter of their browsers not being able to actually parse it for some reason.  I was wondering if perhaps these users have not been updating their Java runtime settings and if that is effecting their browsers.  Really, I'm at a loss here.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use .click or put it in a method and call it from the onclick attribute of the submit button.

Comment: or put your code inside `$(function(){//code here});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. You should Use .on() to attach event handlers.
Could it be that some users are using a cached version of older jQuery while others are using a newer version ?

Comment: only until they close and re-open their browser, and only if the website is using a local copy of jQuery. Possible though.

Comment: yes I know this is not very likely to occur, but who knows ? With scripts running differently on different client, my first concern is always to check whether the client are indeed using the same scripts... also I don't know how the JS is loaded, maybe there's some conditionnal statment involved or so...

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any Javascript errors? If it's not parsing jQuery then it should give an error upon encountering a dollar sign.